# Alamofire response delegate never runs

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm just starting to play with Swift, so I apologize for any inaccuracies in my language about my problem.  I've looked over the last few days, but haven't seen anyone with this specific problem, so I'm assuming I'm doing something obviously wrong.

This is a very basic Mac console application. Xcode Version 6.3.2, and I believe Swift 1.2.

The request is made, and I can see the progress delegate being called and printing results. The response delegate, however, is never called, though the request has completed.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
var waiting = true;

let req = request(.GET, "http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
.progress { (bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) -> Void in
    println("Entering progress")
    println("\(totalBytesRead) of \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
}
.response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
    println("Received response")
    waiting = false;
}

debugPrintln(req)

while(waiting)
{}
```

Edit: I'm bringing the Alamofire code directly into my project instead of referencing a framework, which is why I can call `request` without the `Alamofire.request(...`

Comment: `response` executes on the main thread, which is blocked by the `while` statement. Synchronous networking is inadvisable, but the correct way to do it would be to use a dispatch_semaphore instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment mattt. I'll look into that for situations such as this console app.

Comment: So if `response` executes on the main thread, does that mean that `progress` doesn't?  Because that delegate is being called despite the blocking while loop.

Comment: It would have to. It's not a delegate method—that's a closure that is executed on the network execution thread.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
while(waiting)
```

is blocking the main thread.
remove it, or use a dispatch_semaphore instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't occupy or block the main "thread" with waiting because Alamofire uses the same queue. It will then never run -- a deadlock!

This works:

```
repeat {
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
} while waiting
```